# Assign two different jquery click events to same item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button on my site that has jquery that changes some css of other elements on click.

I want to assign another function to reverse the css changes when the button is clicked a second time.

```
$('.mobileitem').click(function(){
   $('.bottomfooter').css("bottom","75px");
   $('#mobilefoot').css("display", "block");
});
```

I want to be able to click `.mobileitem` again and have the css change to bottom:0 display:none for their respective elements.

Each time I click the .mobileitem it should go between the two.

I think it is .toggle() but not sure of the proper syntax or if there is a better way

Comment: you can do this with toggle too for that you have to just create two css classes that you want to shuffle with.... For reference follow this http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.mobileitem').click(function(){
   var bot_val="75px";
   var dis_val="block";
   if($('.bottomfooter').css("bottom")==bot_val){
       bot_val="0px";
   }
   if($('#mobilefoot').css("display")==dis_val){
       dis_val="none";
   }
   $('.bottomfooter').css("bottom", bot_val);
   $('#mobilefoot').css("display", dis_val);
});
```

This should work!

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rpsw5/)

```
function toggleClickEvents(item, click1, click2){
    $(item).off('click').on('click', function(){
        click1();
        toggleClickEvents(item, click2, click1);
    });
}
```

Or just use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) although it is deprecated and possibly removed. (Not sure what the replacement is)

Comment: +1 for mentioning that .toggle() had been deprecated. Well, it had been deprecated in 1.8 & removed in jQuery 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.mobileitem').toggle(function(){
   $('.bottomfooter').css("bottom","75px");
   $('#mobilefoot').css("display", "block");
}, function(){
   $('.bottomfooter').css("bottom","0px");
   $('#mobilefoot').css("display", "none");
});
```

Here's a neater, cleaner example using TOGGLE functionality. 
It'll work as well. :)

Comment: Tried that before posting.  for some reason that seems to apply `display:none` to `.mobileitem' on document ready

Comment: @gteh: `apply display:none to .mobileitem'`? But when did we apply display:none to '.mobileitem'?

Answer (score 0):

you can write two css classes

```
.bottom75
{
  bottom: 75px;
  display: block;
}

.bottom0
{
  bottom: 0px;
  display: none;
}
```

On click event

```
$('.mobileitem').click(function(){
  $(this).hasClass('bottom75') ? $(this).addClass('bottom0'): $(this).addClass('bottom75');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('.mobileitem').click(function(){
   $(".bottomfooter, #mobilefoot").toggle(function() {
   $('.bottomfooter).css('bottom','75px');
   $('#mobilefoot').css('display', 'block');
   }, function () {
   $('.bottomfooter').css('bottom','0');
   $('#mobilefoot').css('display', 'none');
   });
});
```

Comment: You missed closing parentheses & braces... :)